# concat multiple columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Have Account Table, in which have project_id, project_name, document_count, account_name.
One account have multiple project. I want collect all projects data for each account.

Database: AWS Aurora
Model:

```
class Account(BASE):
    """
    This class represents Account table
    """
    __tablename__ = 'Account'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    project_id = Column(String(255), unique=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_at = Column(
        DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now
    )
    account_name = Column(String(255))
    document_count= Column(SmallInteger, default=0)
    account_id = Column(String(255))
    project_name = Column(String(255))
    status = Column(String(10))
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.project_id = data["project_id"]
        self.account_name = data["account_name"]
        self.document_count= data["document_count"]
        self.account_id = data["account_id"]
        self.project_name = data["project_name"]
        self.status = data["status"]
```

Previously I have to concat only project ID of each account. I used following

```
table = Account
column_name = project_id
filters = Some condition
columns_to_select = ["account_id", "account_name"]
label = project_ids
```

Following sqlalchemy code for that (Working code)

```
        data = session.query( 
            func.group_concat(
               getattr(table, column_name)
            ).label(label), 
            *[getattr(table, column) for column in columns_to_select]
        ).filter_by(**filters).group_by(getattr(table, group_by)).all()
```

Output of above code:

```
[{'project_ids': '8882-4ba7-a86e-016d1d58bbc1', 'account_id': '2389-4ea7-9ff2-94fc15eaa981', 'account_name': 'ABC'}, {'project_ids': 'd081-4956-8604-365d6976a842,cu61-34556-76704-323fs6976a845', 'account_id': '9f7d-460f-9de1-800e457d91ef', 'account_name': 'XYZ'}]
```

Now I want "project_name" and document count in result.
I am not able do

Input:

```
table = Account
column_names = project_id, project_name, document_count
filters = Some condition
columns_to_select = ["account_id", "account_name"]
label = collected_data
```

expected output:

```
[
  {
    'collected_data': [('8882-4ba7-a86e-016d1d58bbc1', "project-001", 23)], 
    'account_id': '2389-4ea7-9ff2-94fc15eaa981', 'account_name': 'ABC'
  }, 
  {
    'collected_data': [('d081-4956-8604-365d6976a842, "project-002", 12), 
                       ('cu61-34556-76704-323fs6976a845', "project-003", 212)]
    'account_id': '9f7d-460f-9de1-800e457d91ef', 'account_name': 'XYZ'}
]
```

Please let me know anyone can help me on this..

Comment: Are you looking for SQL or SQLAlchemy answer?

Comment: I required SQLAlchemy, but SQL query also fine, I can convert to SQLAlchemy

Comment: @IljaEverilä: added. working on aws aurora database, added model schema and working query

Comment: @IljaEverilä: MySQL